# Script not closing fast enough - premature end of script headers?

Tags: php, javascript

I've got the following script to check for new messages and if there are some for the menu bar to include brackets with the number of new messages. The idea being that you don't have to refresh the page to see that you've got new messages in your inbox. The script works great, however, it's causing the server some problems and comes back with the process response - ***'premature end of script headers'*** - any ideas how I can resolve this?

**Header Javavascript:**

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#inmsg").load("./get_user_msg.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#inmsg").load('./get_user_msg.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 3000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

});
</script>
```

**get_user_msg.php:**

```
<?
session_start();

include "conf/config.php";

$session_memberid = $_SESSION['memberid'];

$head_getnewmsg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_to = '$session_memberid' AND msg_read = 'no'");
$num_new_msg = mysql_num_rows($head_getnewmsg);

if ( $num_new_msg != '0' ) {
$head_show_new_msg = " ($num_new_msg)";
} else { $head_show_new_msg = ''; }

echo "inbox{$head_show_new_msg}";

?>
```

Comment: this happens everytime?

Comment: Probably you atingil limit cpu with it the server crashed. The most correct for this type of scenario is to work with sockets, because if we make a request every 3 seconds times the number of users, server certainly can't endure

Comment: you should use full openning tag in PHP : `<?php  ... ?>`

Comment: @Sharky - no only once every now and then because I think the server limits processes.

Answer (score 1):

## Possible causes of the problem:

1. Upgrading or downgrading to a different version of PHP can leave residual options in the httpd.conf. Check the current version of PHP using php -v on the command line and search for any lines mentioning another version in the httpd.conf. If you find them, comment them out, distill the httpd.conf and restart apache.
2. The RLimitCPU and RLimitMEM directives in the httpd.conf may also be responsible for the error if a script was killed due to a resource limit.
3. A configuration problem in suEXEC, mod_perl, or another third party module can often interfere with the execution of scripts and cause the error. If these are the cause, additional information relating to specifics will be found in the apache error_log.
4. If suphp’s log reaches 2GB in size or larger you may see the premature end of scripts headers error. See what the log contains and either gzip it or null it. Restart apache and then deal with any issues that the suphp log brought to light. The suphp log is located at: /usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log
5. The script’s permissions may also cause this error. CGI scripts can only access resources allowed for the User and Group specified in the httpd.conf. In this case, the error may simply be pointing out that an unauthorized user is attempting to access a script.

Comment: if your going to copy+paste, also backlink to source. That text is on many websites, including: http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-error-premature-end-of-script-headers/. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18548854/3770004 for example

Answer (score 0):

ok i can see a number of issues in your setup here:

1. Surely you can reduce that timeout interval to something more realistic say like every 1 minute... or 30 seconds, if you think of most email clients they usually only look for new mail every 5 minutes or so, why not try start there and see if that reduces load on your server for starters.
2. you need to profile your count script, using microtime(true); at the beginning and end of the script to see the amount of seconds it takes to run this script, you may also want to check if there is an index on the 'msg_read' and 'msg_to' columns.
3. you can read more about the premature error from apache here : [500 Server error: Premature end of script headers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336757/500-server-error-premature-end-of-script-headers)

Comment: A good solution to work with realtime applications is to use socket, however, is not so simple to implement because you depend on an application communicating via TCP, moreover, if there are many queries in the database, you should have a good server.

Comment: If I changed it from 3000 to 30000 would that help? That'd then check every thirty seconds right? :)

Comment: this can help, with everything, depending on the number of users logged doing this kind of request, can cause problems once you have a physical limit of server providing the application.

His approach requisition called Long Polling, where you do from time to time a request to server, this generates traffic on the server, ie, it is not the best solution.

Push technology
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Socket
http://socketo.me/

Comment: Yes, I would start there, turn it down to 30000 ms and let it run for awhile, then see if the error occurs again.