# Premature end of script - causing internal error 500 of php files

Tags: php, apache

first I wish you a happy new year!

I got the following problem: 
I receive an Internal Error 500 when trying to open one of my websites on my server which uses .php files. All Domains configured on this user don't work. The Domains configured on other users are working fine.

Checking out the error log gave me the error "Premature end of script". Until yesterday everything worked fine and I haven't made changes since than.

I checked out the following possibilities:

- APC in php.ini -> doesn't exists in my php ini (https://www.drupal.org/node/213260)
- File Permissions ([500 Server error: Premature end of script headers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336757/500-server-error-premature-end-of-script-headers))
- RLimitCPU and RLimitMEM
- some other things with general configuration, but they can't be the reason because my other sites with php are working fine

I compared the Apache config of the different domains but couldn't find a relevant difference. Unluckily I changed the rights of the files in this directory and now my ftp isn't working anymore (set them to 705). Any Ideas on both problems?

Server is CentOS 6.7 with PHP 5.3.3 and Webmin Interface 
FTP Server is ProFTPD

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without giving at least an example of the code, you are asking everyone to guess what the issue is.

Comment: It is enough that the file is .php - even if there isn't any php code inside the error is shown. However here an example that should work, but actually throws the error: `code`<?php
php_info();
?>`code`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the premature end of script. The quota of the user was more than full, which was done by a failure in a cronjob. *facepalm*